# a wierd 'File' in web app directory failing WAR

Tags: file, windows-7, war

This may sound like a wierd question, but I am having this issue with a file (0 bytes in size) with a name like mymap.register.User of type "File" , in Windows 7 HomePremium.
When I try to delete this file it says cannot find the file, I cannot do any operation on this file basically (open, edit, delete, rename etc).
this file is located in my grails project in web-app/js directory, so when I try to build the WAR it fails saying cannot find this file. I am really stuck with this 'pseudo' file which is not clearing up from my system.

Thanks
Priyank